# Example to show that $f(A-B)$ is not necessarily a subset of $f(A) - f(B)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose f : X→Y is a function and A,B ⊆ X.

I am trying to come up with counterexample to show $f(A-B)$ is not always a subset of $f(A) - f(B)$ and this is what I have so far:

$A = \{1,2,3\}$

$B = \{2,3,4\}$

$f(A-B) = \{1\}$

$f(A) - f(B) = \{1,4\}$

Is the counterexample I have provided correct? If it is not correct then what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What's $f$?  What is the question?

Comment: f: X -> Y and A,B is a subset of X.

Comment: What does $A-B$ mean?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question, it is not clear.  You seem to be giving an example of something...but you don't tell us what $X,Y,f$ are nor what property you are after.

Comment: You have to define clearly what $f: X \to Y$ is, and make sure $f$ is a function, before you write your sets $f(A\setminus B)$ and $f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

Answer (score 5):

My interpretation of the question is that you seek a function $f : X \to Y$ and subsets $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $f(A-B) \nsubseteq f(A)-f(B)$.

My advice would be to take $f : X \to Y$ to be any constant function—with domain and codomain of your choosing, say $X=Y=\mathbb{Z}$ or something—and pick subsets $A,B \subseteq X$ with $B \subsetneqq A$.

Comment: Also $B\neq\varnothing$ is requested here.